# Do outgoing requests generated from tomcat go through apache http server?

Tags: java, apache, tomcat

I was trying to modify outgoing requests (change its destination for test automation purpose) from apache http server.
Till now I haven't found any relevant solution, the only relavant one i found was 'proxypass' directive. But it maps to a incoming request and then creates a proxy for that (correct me if i am wrong).

So need clarification for my understanding, do outgoing requests generated from some xx controller goes through http server? If thats not the case, the headers and origin are added to the requests programmatically (when its required for such calls)?. Kindly clarify

Comment: The web/http server is just that: a server that responds to requests. If Tomcat needs to be the client, i.e. make requests to other servers, then Apache doesn't see any of this. Afaik your code would make those calls anyways so it's up to you to add the needed headers. You could try and use some outbound proxy though.

Comment: @Thomas so as long the requests go through http server, i can have handle over the requests, but if requests are generated from the code then http server doesnt have any handle on it.. thanks for the clarification. I can accept your answer